# Does the new update of mosaic (1.8.3) not work on mac?

Tags: r, mosaic, r-mosaic

I notice that the mosaic package was updated a few days ago (1.8.3). Since then, I keep getting an error message that mosaic can't load.

```
    > library(mosaic)
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mosaic’:
    object ‘compare’ is not exported by 'namespace:mosaicCore'
```

The package installed, and it works on a PC. I've tried reinstalling R and R studio to be sure but I keep getting the same error. Anyone who has had the same problem or figured out how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It works fine on a Mac (it was developed on a Mac).

I'm not sure how you did your installation, but you also need to have an updated version of mosaicCore.  Looks like that didn't happen for some reason.

I'd suggest updating mosaicData and ggformula as well, if your update method didn't trigger those already.  All four packages went to CRAN last week.  If it has been awhile, you might do update.packages().

Comment: That was the issue, I think something happened when I was installing a lot of packages at once. Before I updated mosaicCore I also had to uninstall ggformula. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had other people in my class that had the same issue. Similar to the above answer, i had to:

1. Uninstall/delete the package ggformula
2. Update the package mosaicCore
3. Reinstall ggformula
4. Reinstall mosaic

That is how i was able to resolve the issue.